# Solving non-linear differential equation (2-order, with singularity)

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, numerical-methods, differential-equations

Well, I have to numerically solve the a non-linear DE for x in (0,1), which is presented in the picture below. Moreover, I know, that at x=0 y should be equal to chosen constant (0.25), and at x = 1 y should be equal to zero. And at x = 0 y'(0)=0.

[image: DE]

Note: a and c are constants.

I'm trying to solve it with using `solve_bvp` with boundary conditions (y(0)=0.25, y'(1)=0). But there are a couple of problems. Firstly, I found a solution how to deal with the singularity at x = 0, but I don't know what to do with y = 0 at x = 1.

There is my Python code.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import integrate
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def eqs(x,y):
    a = 1240.5
    k = 12
    dydx = y[1]
    dudx = y[1]**2/y[0]+a*y[0]**2-(k**2*(k-1)**2)*y[0]*x**(2*k-4)/4
    return np.vstack((dydx, dudx))

x = np.linspace(0,1,101)
y0 = np.zeros((2,r.size))
y0[0] = 0.25
y0[1] = 0
S = np.array([[0.0,0.0],[0.0,-1.0]])

def bc(ya, yb):
    return np.array([ya[0]-0.25,yb[1]])

sol = integrate.solve_bvp(eqs,bc,x,y0,S=S)
plt.plot(x,sol.sol(x)[0])
```

The graph y(x):

[image]

It should look like this:

[image: Ideal graph]

What am I doing wrong?

I tried to solve it for different boundary conditions.

Comment: Why doesn't that plot of the true solution have the same domain?

Comment: (1) Your second derivative equation doesn't match the equation you shared in the photo. You're missing the -y'/x term. (2) You have a second-order ODE but seem to want to satisfy 4 boundary conditions, i.e. y(0) = 0.25, y'(0) = 0, y(1) = 0, and y'(1) = 0. You cannot do that.

Comment: If you set `y(x)=y(0)*exp(u(x))`, then the equation simplifies. This might stabilize the solution process of the BVP solver. // Always check `sol.success` and `sol.message`.